# How to I substract time in PHP along with AM/PM

Tags: php, time

I have time format say:

```
$start_time; (example: 1:30 PM)
$system_time; (example: 8:20 AM)        
echo $time_left_for_discussion = $start_time - $system_time;
```

I want to substract $start_time - $system_time. But its not showing the correct result.

How can I deal with this kind of time substraction?

Comment: Convert both time in time stamp by using strtotime.

Comment: Difference must be less than 24h? Should consider changing the summer and winter time?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) on both times, and substract those.

```
$TimeStart = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'g:i A', $start_time );
$TimeEnd = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'g:i A', $end_time );

$Interval = $TimeStart->diff( $TimeEnd );
$time_left = $Interval->h . 'h' . $Interval->m 'm';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
  $d1 = strtotime('1:30 PM');
  $d2 = strtotime('8:20 AM');
   $diff = abs($d1-$d2);

  echo "Difference is $diff secs";

?>
```

Comment: Its not showing the correct different if I am converting seconds into the hours using `gmdate("h:i:s",abs($d1 - $d2))`

Comment: @jks I am getting it as 5hours and 10 min ... which I think is correct.. ?

Comment: it showing diff between 5:00 PM and 9:29 AM is 7.5166666666667

Comment: I am considering am/pm also here for getting difference

Comment: its correct ,, I think difference is 7 hours and 30 min .. mean 7.5 hours .. whats the problem .... ?

Comment: and sorry for my first comment . I misunderstod it .. u can also use gmdate("h:i:s",abs($d1 - $d2)) here

Comment: PLease see this ... http://codepad.org/aITVbqUY I have tried to explain .. if still you have any confusion please ask me

Comment: What I want to achieve is : Suppose its 7:00 AM in India and its 4:00 AM in Country X. The discussion is going to be started at 10:00 AM India Time. Then for all countries it should show as discussion to be started after 3 hours.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27077/discussion-between-new-developer-and-jka)

Answer (score 1):

you will want to look at the [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [strtotime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) functions.

the way to deal with such a case is to convert the dates into [unix timestamps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), subtract one timestamp form another and then recreate a date string from the resulting timestamp.

Note: the [time()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) function will return the current system time(-stamp)

Answer (score 1):

Can I recommend you take a look at this http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

This is String to time, it is very useful.

Have a good day :D